# implement chat service using socket programming in php

Tags: php, sockets, socket.io

I wanted to implement a chat service in **PHP** for which I am using socket programming.
Below are the client and server file I found to implement it:

Server.php

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/* Allow the script to hang around waiting for connections. */
set_time_limit(0);

/* Turn on implicit output flushing so we see what we're getting
 * as it comes in. */
ob_implicit_flush();

$address = '192.168.1.53';
$port = 10000;

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)) === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
}

if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) {
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

if (socket_listen($sock, 5) === false) {
    echo "socket_listen() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
}

do {
    if (($msgsock = socket_accept($sock)) === false) {
        echo "socket_accept() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
        break;
    }
    /* Send instructions. */
    $msg = "\nWelcome to the PHP Test Server. \n" .
        "To quit, type 'quit'. To shut down the server type 'shutdown'.\n";
    socket_write($msgsock, $msg, strlen($msg));

    do {
        if (false === ($buf = socket_read($msgsock, 2048, PHP_NORMAL_READ))) {
            echo "socket_read() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($msgsock)) . "\n";
            break 2;
        }
        if (!$buf = trim($buf)) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($buf == 'quit') {
            break;
        }
        if ($buf == 'shutdown') {
            socket_close($msgsock);
            break 2;
        }
        $talkback = "PHP: You said '$buf'.\n";
        socket_write($msgsock, $talkback, strlen($talkback));
        echo "$buf\n";
    } while (true);
    socket_close($msgsock);
} while (true);

socket_close($sock);
?>
```

Client.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "<h2>TCP/IP Connection</h2>\n";

/* Get the port for the WWW service. */
$service_port = getservbyname('www', 'tcp');

/* Get the IP address for the target host. */
$address = gethostbyname('www.example.com');

/* Create a TCP/IP socket. */
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if ($socket === false) {
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}

echo "Attempting to connect to '$address' on port '$service_port'...";
$result = socket_connect($socket, $address, $service_port);
if ($result === false) {
    echo "socket_connect() failed.\nReason: ($result) " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($socket)) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "OK.\n";
}

$in = "HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$in .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
$in .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
$out = '';

echo "Sending HTTP HEAD request...";
socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));
echo "OK.\n";

echo "Reading response:\n\n";
while ($out = socket_read($socket, 2048)) {
    echo $out;
}

echo "Closing socket...";
socket_close($socket);
echo "OK.\n\n";
?>
```

But I am not able to understand one thing in this process.I will be hosting this application to a remote server and both the files will reside in that server.Now the line **socket_connect()** in **client.php** would try to connect with the IP address I pass to this function as a parameter,and,for the application to work I need both the server.php and client.php files.

Now, let us assume that the client.php sends a request to a particular user X,now for the user X to accept that request,he should also have a server.php file to accept the HTTP request made,but the server.php is on the server where the application is hosted.So how the user X's machine will be able to accept the request?

Can anyone please tell how this will be handled or please correct me if I misunderstood the process?

Comment: the client would need SOME kind of a "server" to accept connections request from the client. It doesn't have to be PHP, but it would be a "server" of some sort. But that's HIGHLY unlikely to work anyways. most "users" are behind some kind of NAT gateway/firewall, and cannot be reached from "outside".

Comment: how would I be able to provide SOME kind of a "server" to the user?

Comment: `socket.io` is a javascript application that works on the server- and clientside of your website. You may want to use javascript to connect to the socket.

Comment: thanks,I will look for socket.io, but how it was implemented without using this?

Comment: for socket.io I have the same doubt,wouldn't it be required for it to be present at the client side as well?

Comment: I saw some examples using socket.io but all were being run on localhost only.